# Need help creating rules for a .clr to help export some data to a Excel file

Tags: docview

Basically this data is in a report that I can view using 'Unicenter Outpout Management Document Viewer'..... Once I see the results I am able Export using the following parameters
Export Type = Worksheet
Worksheet Format = .XLS

I am also able to load a Column Rule Name file that includes the rules I would likle applied i.e 'COLRULE BLANKLINE DISCARD'

Below is the example of how the data is presented. I have changed some values due to privacy, I have made no changes to format or spacing.

```
                      XXX - DI tape              DATE:  25SEP2017                  Page: 0001
```

Header:  File ID:   CN15  Processing Date:  20170923

Detail

SL Agt    Reason Cd      Policy No.     Prem Amt.       Comm Rate       Comm Amt.       Agt Shr
 Comm Yr   Ins Name       Paid To Date   Cov Code        GW Agt          SL Agt Name     Annual Prem Amt

001234    CSERF          0012345678           3.92            5.0000            0.20-   100.000
  17       EVESO          20171028       00220           652348          ABCDE                47.04
 001234    CSERF          0012345678          70.30            5.0000            3.52-   100.000
  17       EVESO          20171028       30086           652348          ABCDE               843.60
 001234    CSERF          0012345678          14.83            5.0000            0.74-   100.000
  17       EVESO          20171028       30015           652348          ABCDE               177.96
 001234    CSERF          0012345678          26.28            5.0000            1.31-   100.000
  17       EVESO          20171028       30086           652348          ABCDE               315.36

Since the data seams to automatically go to the next row I have no idea what type of rule can be applied to have the headers go on row 1, and then read the data properly.

If anyone has an idea please help.

Thank you in advance.

Cheers